# multiplication of df values within a column in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a `tmp` dataframe where I perform the following operation for each column

```
M*sin(freq + phase) where for col A: M=1, freq=1 and phase=1
```

Input:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1],
                       'B': [2, 2, 2],
                       'C': [3, 3, 3]},
                       index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'])



tmp = pd.DataFrame([], dtype=object)
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    for j in range(df.shape[0]):
        test=df.iloc[0:j+1,0:1]*np.sin((df.iloc[1:j+2,0:1]) + 
             df.iloc[2:j+3,0:1])
        tmp=tmp.append(test,ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
       A  B  C
ONE    1  2  3
TWO    1  2  3
THREE  1  2  3

      A
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   1.0
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  NaN
11  NaN
12  NaN
13  NaN
14  NaN
15  NaN
16  1.0
17  NaN
18  NaN
19  NaN
20  NaN
21  NaN
22  NaN
23  NaN
24  NaN
25  1.0
26  NaN
```

Expected Output:for column 1, repeat for remaining cols B and C

```
 0.9092974268256817   -1.5136049906158564   -0.8382464945967776
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do

```
>>> df.prod(axis=0)
A     1
B     8
C    27
dtype: int64
```

?

Comment: No need of `axis=0`

Comment: true, but "explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: Make a better example with clear input and expected output and I'll update my answer

Comment: @ignoring_gravity. I have edited my original post. hope its clear now.

Comment: not to me, but maybe someone else will answer. else, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.product.html) with [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`transpose(.T)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
In [467]: df.product().to_frame().T
Out[467]: 
   A  B   C
0  1  8  27
```